# let text attached to graphic

Tags: graphics, text

[image]

I'm trying to made a first page of journal. I've used this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,portrait]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref} %--- per i link
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{multicol} %------ per formattare pagine a più colonne
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox} %--- per le caselle di testo I pagina
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath} %----- uso font garamond
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}%----- uso font garamond
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%----- uso font garamond
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
%------ set colori del link
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
    pdftitle={Overleaf Example},
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
    }

 %----- dimensione della pagina ------
 \geometry{
 a3paper,
 total={297mm,420mm},
 left=15mm,
 top=15mm,
 right=15mm,
 bottom=0mm,
 }
\usepackage{showframe}

\tcbset{colback=white!5!!,colframe=red!15!white!60!,size=small,
fonttitle=\bfseries,width=0.333\textwidth,box align=top,height=7.5cm,nobeforeafter}

\begin{document}
%----  inserimento banner --------
\begin{figure}[t]
    \includegraphics[width=267mm]{banner_corto.eps}
    \centering
\end{figure}

%\vspace*{-\topskip}
\noindent
%------ I box ---------------
\begin{tcolorbox}[adjusted title=\hyperlink{1_1}{bla bla bla bla bla
```

and much more, but how you can see in the image, the pink box start some space below the blue image. Not attached I mean.
I'm wondering how can I "attach" this two element. what is the instruction that made this space

Comment: this is part of your page design so don't use `figure` it is not a float. also don't use `\usepackage{epstopdf}`  this comment is wrong `\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath} %----- uso font garamond` newtx is a Times Roman clone, not Garamond. This comment is also wrong (and the package has already been loaded specifying T1 just above) `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%----- uso font garamond`

Comment: so if it is a figure, how can I show that?

Comment: `figure` is unrelated to image inclusion (that is `\includegraphics`) the point of `figure` is to mark its content as a floating insert that is not part of the document flow and may be moved to another part of the document to help with page breaking. (also placing `\centering` after the thing you are centering only works in some cases, so is working essentially by accident here.)